# python "cannot import name 'geolite2'"

Tags: python

I'm in trouble with import module using python

Here's the list when I list my installed package using cmd "pip list"

```
geoip2
maxmindb
pip
python-geoip
python-geoip-geolite2
request
setuptools
wheel
```

my python code starts

```
import sys
from geoip import geolite2

<my code>
```

the import error occured at line 2.

I have no idea about this..Is there anyone who can help me?

My code is running on Windows. Please help me

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've installed `geoip2` and you're looking to use  `geoipe2` (extra "e").
In addition, in your import you're using `geoip`

Comment: thanks problems solved in other way though. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Chloe can you please respond to ddofborg's comment above ?